# jQuery- Loop through buttons add active class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]Good day! I'm new with jQuery.
Please **how do I loop through buttons** to bring out only its contents when I click on it, and change the active class on them each time I click.

I repeated the code below for two more buttons:

```
$("#member-company-btn").on("click", () => {
    $("#member-company-content").show("slow");
    $("#group-company-content").hide("slow");
    $("#abuja-sub-company-content").hide("slow");
    $("#lagos-sub-company-content").hide("slow");
})
$("#group-company-btn").on("click", () => {
    $("#member-company-content").hide("slow");
    $("#group-company-content").show("slow");
    $("#abuja-sub-company-content").hide("slow");
    $("#lagos-sub-company-content").hide("slow");
})
```

This to **add active class** to only the clicked button didn't work.

```
$("#subsidiary-btns .subsidiary-btn").on("click", () => {
    $("button.subsidiary-btn").removeClass("subsidiary-btn-active");
    $(this).addClass("subsidiary-btn-active");
})
```

Thank you

Comment: `this` is written without parentheses. Try `$(this).addClass("subsidiary-btn-active");`

Comment: Thank you for that observation, but that's not the problem.. I've been trying to understand how I can target only a button while removing active from all others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I decided to stay on this till it works, instead of styling differently. And Persistence paid off.
Inspired to make some changes to the code. Below are the images showing a possible solution.

[image: html code]

[image: css code]

[image: javascript code]